# context:component-scan" is not bound

Tags: java, spring

Am new to spring and I know this question has been asked many times, but I had to ask it again.

I guess,I have done appropriate namespace declarations, but still facing the error  `"The prefix "context" for element "context:component-scan" is not bound."`  There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131479/the-prefix-context-for-element-contextcomponent-scan-is-not-bound), but I dint get the answer

Here is my xml document, Is it that my namespace is not correct ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">



    <bean id="point1" class="org.sri.proj.Point">
        <property name="x" value="0" />
        <property name="y" value="0" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="point2" class="org.sri.proj.Point">
        <property name="x" value="10" />
        <property name="y" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.sri.proj"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: You are missing the namespace declaration for `context`.

Comment: I am little confused about these namespace, can you please elaborate ?

Comment: The answers below cover most of it.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Add the `context` namespace declaration to the `beans` tag definition in the application context file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
```

Comment: What is the utility of the namespace ? do I have to update them once I want to migrate to the spring 4 ?

Comment: What do you mean by "utility"? Spring needs to know that the namespace is in use before actually using it, similar to declaring a variable. Namespace declaration needed for all versions of Spring

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you must add

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
```

Before

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
```

So it looks like :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
```

Comment: I added "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" before "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd" but it is still showing me the same error, I even cleaned my project, still no good

Comment: I was missing this "xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" earlier :)

Answer (score 3):

You are missing Context (`http://www.springframework.org/schema/context`) namespace there :

```
<beans:beans xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd 


http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

Add the last line from this code.

Answer (score 3):

## For All time Sake not just simply copy and past. But.

## First see that which comment you used in your xml file.Let say your xml contains the following...

1. `<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.study" />`
2. `<context:annotation-config/>`
3. `<mvc:annotation-driven />`

Then before you copy and past code see that what your really need in the header `<beans:beans section ...`

So ,Do it like this which satisfies the above configuration setting and

## Make sure you clean and build every time after you change your file !!

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.study" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Cheers! Dman!

Answer (score 2):

You should add `xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"`
into your beans xml.