# Spring frame work config issue "prefix context for for element context:annotation-config is not bound"

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am having a weird issue that I can't seem to track down.  I have this working with other servers without a problem, but I can't seem to get this one to work.  The closest post that I see to my problem was this post [The prefix "context" for element "context:component-scan" is not bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131479/the-prefix-context-for-element-contextcomponent-scan-is-not-bound)

All others really were just because the prefix was not in the xml file.  I am hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction here.

Spring XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
  xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
    http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr
    http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
```

So I have that, but getting this error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "context" for element "context:annotation-config" is not bound.
```

Appreciate any help.  Let me know what else I can provide.

Thanks

Comment: Very strange... It certainly looks as though it should just work. Is your XML file definitely encoded in UTF-8? What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Using:
java version "1.6.0_45"

sorry keep hitting enter and posting.  How can I verify UTF-8 encoding for the text file.  Using file is just telling me it is XML.  Opening with OpenOffice doesn't seem to have a problem with it opening it as a UTF-8 doc.  Sorry I don't know another way to test it. 

thanks

Comment: How are you launching your Spring app?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for here.  

This would be using Jetty and I have a class I use to kickstart the server.  Spring is kicked off from in there and then has a web.xml file as well to configure servlets etc.

Comment: Yep, that's what I wanted to know. If you were running in a web application or other. I'll post an answer, which is more of a question really.

Comment: sorry this is kinda summarized.  I will try the test from below.

WebAppContext root = new WebAppContext();
    root.setDescriptor("./WEB-INF/web.xml");
    root.setDisplayName("Root Context");
    root.setSessionHandler(sesh); //Persist Session across restarts of context
    root.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation","classpath:properties/spring.xml");
    root.addEventListener(new org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener());
    root.addEventListener(new SpringInit());

    server.setHandler(root);
    server.start();
    server.join();

Comment: Thanks! Have you done a complete _Clean_ and _Republish_ to Jetty? It could be that Jetty's still looking at an old version of your spring.xml. Finally, have you tried the code I posted as an answer?

Comment: I think I am using Jetty in a more basic manner.  This is what I do so let me know if you think that could be the problem.  I stop the and start it via my java class each time.  when making any code changes I remove all class files within the structure and re-compile each one and start the server again.  Each time I make a change to an XML file I stop and start the server.  I know it is definitely picking up the changes as while working on it of course I have had typos which would make it print other errors.

Answer (score 20):

I was experiencing the same problem until I realized `beans` tag attribute `xmlns:context` was missing. Just added the below lines

```
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
...."
```

Then rebuilt the project.

It worked well then on.

Answer (score 14):

The following works for me:

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
  xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
    http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr
    http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

</beans>
```

When I use the following class to run it:

**Test.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test.xml");
        System.out.println("Finished!");
    }

}
```

Can you please see if this runs for you? You will need the following libraries in the classpath: commons-logging, spring-asm, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-core, and spring-expression.

Please let me know if it worked. If it didn't, please post the full stack-trace. Finally, I used Spring 3.1.1 for the above.

Comment: Looks like that was successful.

Comment: Does that mean there has to be some other error in my code or something?  Any idea what it would be related to if that is the case?

Comment: It's very hard to tell without seeing everything. For a starter, I'd recommend installing an IDE (eg Eclipse, IDEA, Netbeans) for your development. After you've done this, install/setup the appropriate plugin/extension to run Jetty from the IDE. This will save you a lot of time, and will help in the resolution of this problem.

Comment: I am using Eclipse. ;)   Kewl I will see what I can find to kick off Jetty from Eclipse.  Thank you!

Comment: This was the resolution to my problem for everyone searching.  This was my fault I had two copies from GIT running and I was updating the XML file for the wrong one so it was not working right. Once fixing the correct config file it worked.   FYI I did find other articales about order of the namespace.

Answer (score 8):

This error comes when you have `xmlns:context` missing from your spring xml file. So add it. Your beans header should look something like the following -

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd" >

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem but i was able to solve it by moving

from applicationContext.xml to spring-servlet.xml and adding xmlns:context in the spring-servlet.xml