# noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
     <context-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>       
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

application-context.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <!--bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.url}"
    p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" /-->

    <!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc) -->

</beans>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Welcome to Spring Web MVC project</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Hello! This is the default welcome page for a Spring Web MVC project.</p>
        <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname"/>
        <button onclick="cal('uname')">submit</button>
        <div id="msg"></div>
        <script>
            function cal(uname){
                var name = $("#"+uname).val();
                var url = "serv/getMsg?uname="+uname;
                $.ajax({url: url,success: function(data){
                    $('#msg').html(data);
                }});
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

serv.java

```
package com.controller;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/serv")
public class serv {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getMsg",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String getMsg(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){
        System.out.print("here");
        String name = req.getParameter("uname");
        //req.setAttribute("name",name);
        return name;
    }
}
```

I don't knw where it gone wrong..  evry time getting error 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)' . help me to fix this issue....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your web resources are not getting scanned and you are getting 404.
You should add something like this `<context:component-scan base-package="com.web.resouces.package" />` in dispatcher-servlet.xml.Please see this link

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/

Hope this helps.

Comment: i did that but its giving server error--> The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Comment: Are you getting error on server start up or while hitting request /serv ?
Could you please post the error as well?

Comment: on server startup.. error-> nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; The prefix "context" for element "context:component-scan" is not bound.

Comment: Please add  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
in the <beans> tag of your dispatcher-servlet.xml.
Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131479/the-prefix-context-for-element-contextcomponent-scan-is-not-bound